# Check the performance of Chrome Extension

Tags: performance, google-chrome-extension

I want to check the performance of Google Chrome extensions of Chrome (like the loading time of backscripts), its loading time, and memory requirements.  This means I've added an add-on and want to check after adding it their is a decrease in the performance of Chrome or is same. I there any tool for that.

Answer (score 8):

Chrome provides useful tools to monitor your extension through the built-in *Chrome DevTools*.

- If your extension is a popup, right click in it and choose *Inspect element*.
- If your extension runs in background, go to the extensions page and click on the link *background page* of your extension.

In there you can:

- [evaluate network performance](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network)
- [profile the application Timeline](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline)
- [profile the JavaScript execution](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling)

Google Developers' ressources are the best way to learn more about these tools.